# How do I rerun an old workflow in github actions after 30 days of its initial run?

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm looking for a way to rerun the old workflow in github actions which had last run more than a month ago.
I came across this document from github actions https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/re-running-workflows-and-jobs
Is there a way to rerun the old workflow after 30 days of initial run?

Cheers & Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Currently the 30 days seems to be set in stone:

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/re-running-workflows-and-jobs

> You can re-run a workflow run, all failed jobs in a workflow run, or specific jobs in a workflow run up to 30 days after its initial run.

> You cannot re-run jobs in a workflow once its logs have passed their retention limits.

A lower limit on the log retention will impact how long you can re-run for *if* your log retention is lower than 30 days.

Answer (score -1):

[According to the official documentation from GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/usage-limits-billing-and-administration#artifact-and-log-retention-policy), if you have a:

- **Public repository** - You can rerun an old workflow up to 90 days after the initial run. By default, it's 90 days.
- **Enterprise repository** - The maximum time frame for rerunning an old workflow can range from 1 to 400 days.

**IMPORTANT**

- You would only be able to rerun a workflow if its log exists.
- The log retention will apply only to the new workflows that you will run.
- So, even if you updated the log retention of your workflows. If the log of your workflow is already deleted you won't be able to re-run it.

If you want to rerun a workflow, one workaround is to fetch the changes of that particular workflow and commit them again. This will trigger the workflow to run again.

Comment: This seems to be inaccurate, rerunning jobs does not seem to have the same time-frame as the log retention. I have had the log retention on our production repository set to 1 year for many months now, but I can't rerun a job from a month ago even though I can see the logs from the job I want to rerun.